# Github Actions Firebase error "command requires scopes"

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-cli

I am transitioning my CI/CD over to Github Actions and noticed that my prior scripts for deploying Firebase do not work.

When I try to switch projects via `firebase use staging --debug` it errors with the error:

```
[2020-04-14T12:51:59.154Z] > command requires scopes: 
["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
```

If I use `firebase use --debug` to see what project is active, I get

```
Error: No active project
```

These scripts work without fault on CircleCI so I am confused as to why they break on Github Actions. They also work perfectly in my local environment.

I have tried various versions of node, and installing the firebase tools, however they all result in the same error. I have generated a new token generated via `firebase login:ci`.

Here is a sample of my Github Actions workflow:

```
deploy_staging:
    name: Deploy to staging
    needs: eslint_test_build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "10.x"
      ...
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        run: |
          npm install -g firebase-tools
          firebase -V # this will work
          firebase use staging # this will fail
          firebase functions:config:set sentry.dsn=$DSN
          firebase deploy --only hosting:admin --token "$TOKEN" --non-interactive
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.firebase_token }}
```

*--update*

When I just use deploy it works. Is the `deploy` Firebase CLI command the only one allowed for Github Actions?

This works:

```
- name: Deploy to Firebase
  run: |
    npm install -g firebase-tools
    firebase deploy --only hosting:admin --project=staging --token "$TOKEN" --non-interactive
```